# Creating multiple output files with AvroMultipleOutputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, avro

I have a Reducer using AvroKeyOutput as the output format. By default, MapReduce will write all my keys to a single output file. I would like to write to a separate output file for each key value. Avro provides the AvroMultipleOutputs method, but examples are slim. The one provided by Apache [AvroMultipleOutputs](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroMultipleOutputs.html), shows how to pre-configure the various outputs when defining the job. The examples shows:

JOB:
`AvroMultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "avro1", AvroOutputFormat.class, schema);`
`AvroMultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "avro2", AvroOutputFormat.class, null);`

REDUCER:
`amos = new AvroMultipleOutputs(conf);`
`amos.getCollector("avro1", reporter).collect(datum);`
`amos.getCollector("avro2", "A", reporter).collect(datum);`
`amos.getCollector("avro3", "B", reporter).collect(datum);`

But I don't know how many files I will need or what their names are, since it is based on the key values that come out of my reducer. How could I modify this to accommodate dynamic file naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strategy you can use in this situation:

- use a Map-only job (zero reduce tasks)
- have a single named multiple output configuration
- during the `map()` use your key value for the base output path in `AvroMultipleOutputs.write(String namedOutput, Object key, Object value, String baseOutputPath)`

Comment: Thanks, this is a much simpler solution. I was clearly overthinking it.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without a Map-only job?

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming you're still wanting to do this with Map-Reduce, right? You'll need to consider your grouping strategy, and assuming you get (n) keys at each of (r) reducers, you'll get at most r x n multiple output files. Again, use a single name, but make the baseOutputPath value use the string value of your key.

Comment: did this work? which distribution of hadoop are you using?